# AWS AppSync mutation rerendering the view on mutation

Tags: reactjs, aws-appsync

I have test app where I'm subscribing to a list of todos. But my add new todo mutation also optimistically updates the UI.
The problem is it's now refreshing the entire react view and I have no idea why.

This is the culprit, it happens when I run this mutation:

```
export default graphql(addItem, {
  options: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
  },
  props: props => ({
    onAdd: item =>
      props.mutate({
        variables: item,
        optimisticResponse: {
          __typename: 'Mutation',
          addItem: { ...item, __typename: 'Item' }
        },
        update: (proxy, { data: { addItem } }) => {
          let data = proxy.readQuery({ query: listItems });
          data.listItems.items.push(addItem);
          proxy.writeQuery({ query: listItems, data });
        }
      })
  })
})(AddItem);
```

[image]

Comment: Further debugging shows that it's for some reason setting my props.items array to [ ] before updating. Every time it updates. No idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mutating items locally without all the queried fields (in my case "created" is added by the server) causes the entire query mutation to fail but silently. There's a fix on the way: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3267

Hopefully this helps others starting out!